# Getting FCM remoteMessage.getData().size() size is 0

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Why i am getting FCM **data** **payload**(**remoteMessage.getData().size()**) is **0**.Where as i am sending below **data payload**-

'{
data: {
"action": "notification",
"Orientation": "1",
"ScheduleID": "2033",
"ContentID": "25001",
"ActionUrl": "some url",
"ImgUrl": "image url",
"Title": "Alien",
"ContentText": "Superb !!"
},
"condition": "('abc' in topics || 'xyz' in topics)",
"time_to_live": 86400
}'

And when trying to get the value of the "**action**" field by using the below code then getting **null**.

```
Map<String, String> hashMap = remoteMessage.getData();
                action = hashMap.get("action");
```

Please let me know why i am getiing this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your `data` is a JSONObject not a JSONArray. why you require the size of your jsonobject?
remember, normally we use the size only for JSONArray not for jsonobject.
What you should do is, simply pick the required data from your `data` and use it.

Comment: It's an FCM data-payload and I am trying to get the data-payload by using remoteMessage.getData()  function. So that I can access all field which is written in the data-payload.